# update StreetView programmatically with Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am wondering if it possible to programmatically to continually update the coordinates for a google maps street view API? Thanks and code snippet might be helpful

Answer (score 8):

Once you have [StreetViewPanorama](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanorama) you can update programmatically the position or the point of view like this :

```js
var panorama = map.getStreetView();// or new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(div);

// update position of StreetView
panorama.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573,-71.098326));

// update the point of view
panorama.setPov({
  heading: 34,
  pitch: 10,
  zoom: 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create div map container

```
<div id="panrama" style="width: 400px; height: 400px"></div>
```

Automatic rotating using JavaScript:

```
var     pano;
var     latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.897526, -77.0370613);

var panoOptions = {
    position: latlng,
    pov: {
        heading: 0,
        pitch: 0
    }
};

pano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById('panorama'), 
    panoOptions);

window.setInterval(function() {
    var pov = pano.getPov();
    pov.heading += 0.2;
    pano.setPov(pov);
}, 10);
```

Example: [Virtual Tour White House](http://theoryapp.com/my/web/rotating-panorama.html)

Credits: [theoryapp.com](http://theoryapp.com/rotating-street-view-panorama-using-google-maps/)